# Whole screen manipulation in C for Linux

Tags: c, linux, screen

I'm looking for ways to manipulate whole screen (example change color tones, create effects, etc) and not just for one window or separated full screen output. Instead, everything you see on your screen, desktop, browser windows, etc, etc. All this from one program. Running as root is not problem.

The purpose is neurological experimentation with human vision, while the subjects use their computer normally.

Comment: Sounds like a job for graphics driver.

Comment: Isn't that called a "skin"?

Comment: Like [f.lux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F.lux)?

Comment: f.lux can only change color tones, not to add anything to the screen. Otherwise it is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Magnus Johansson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536621/1475978) already mentioned, you could use the gamma compensation curves for this.

For details on how this is done with the Xorg X server, examine the [`set_gamma_info()`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/tree/xrandr.c) function in the xrandr utility sources. The function implements both gamma correction and software brightness controls, but it also could implement color balance.  It cannot replace red with green or blue, or do hue-based mapping, however.

Essentially, each of the red, green, and blue color component values is compensated using a look-up table similar to

```
red_transmitted_to_display   = red_lut[red_component];
green_transmitted_to_display = green_lut[green_component];
blue_transmitted_to_display  = blue_lut[blue_component];
```

by the hardware, with zero indicating zero intensity, and some maximum value indicating maximum intensity. The xrandr interface provides functions that tell you the depth of the color components in the look-up tables (how many entries each has), and get and set the tables themselves.

---

If you want to do more fine-grained color mapping, like turning dark reds bluish, but bright reds toward greens, or hue mapping in general, you should limit support to some compositing window managers, for example compiz. You then would need to implement a Compiz plugin, that does the necessary color conversions as a pixel shader.

A compositing window manager is one that uses a memory buffer to draw the contents of the display first, then draws that buffer to the actual display or displays.

Compiz supports plugins, that can modify how windows and their contents are displayed, by manipulating the data (in hardware, by *shaders*) before it is sent to the actual display. Some plugins change how windows/views/entire screens are placed, producing 3D effects. Others, *pixels shaders* in particular, operate on each pixel displayed, and can manipulate their color in any way desired. It is even possible to apply the manipulation to only some windows, and not others, and control that at run time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I'm looking for something more powerful (like what Compiz plugin can do), but not that system specific. There is no standard way to do this in Linux?

Comment: @user279078: Not all systems work like Microsoft Windows does.  Perhaps you should focus your efforts on Windows only? It should match your expectations and problem solving approach much better.

Comment: I'm working on very small pilot study. My test team and I are all using  Linux only, though no one is running Compiz. I have suspicion that video memory is accessible in some way, maybe kernel offers something...

Comment: @user279078: I see. The problem is that when compiz is not in use, the X server writes directly to the video memory, and your use case involves modifying that data at exactly that point.  Other than modifying the X server itself, to do that transformation to all data it writes, I don't see how you can do full color manipulation without a compositing window manager.  I'd say your test team should move to using compiz, to allow that kind of manipulation with a simple compiz plugin.